# Routing document-relative static urls in MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, routes

I'm integrating a JavaScript library into an ASP.NET MVC3 web app. The library assumes it will be installed next to the page that references it, and so it uses document-relative URLs to find its components.

For example, the default directory layout looks like

```
container-page.html
jslibrary/
    library.js
    images/
        icon.png
    extensions/
        extension.js
        extension-icon.png
```

However, I want to reference the library from the view in `/Home/edit`. I install the library in the default `Scripts\jslibrary\`  When I reference the library in the view in `Views\Home\edit.cshtml`, the library's document-relative links like

```
images/icon.png
```

end up as requests to

```
http://localhost/Home/images/icon.png
```

which results in a File Not Found (404) error. How do I construct a route to look for

```
{anyControllerName}/images/{anyRemainingPathInfo}
```

and serve up

```
http://localhost/Scripts/jslibrary/images/{anyRemainingPathInfo}
```

?

(full disclosure: I'm still on IIS 6 in Production, and not much chance of going to IIS7 any time soon, so if this is better done at the IIS level, please account for IIS6. Thanks!)

Comment: Just to be clear: from `~/Views/Home/Edit.cshtml` you want to reference `~/Scripts/Home/Edit/jslibrary/`?

Comment: That would be OK, but ideally I'd want `~/Views/Home/Edit.cshtml` to  reference `~/Scripts/jslibrary/` -- no directory representing the controller/action in the path to the JS lib. That way, the JS lib can be referenced easily from more than one view. The problem is that the JS lib has internal relative references, e.g. `./somefile.js` When the view loads under the route URL, that becomes a ref to `/Home/Edit/jslibrary/somefile.js`, which I need to rewrite as `/Scripts/jslibrary/somefile.js`

Comment: Erm then what prevents you from using the `Url.Content` helper? Like `<script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/scripts/jslibrary/foo.js")"></script>`? I don't understand what the problem is here. In your question you seem to be talking about some images. Where and how are you referencing those images? If you reference them from CSS simply use relative (to the .css file) paths. And if you are referencing them from your view with the `<img>` tag then simply use the `Url.Content` helper once again.

Comment: @Darin,the jslib has script-relative refs to the PNG, and also to other .JS files.

Comment: Why not reorganize your code so that those urls are passed as parameters from the main view? How are those PNG an JS resources currently being referenced? What is the purpose?

Comment: The library is a complex 3rd-party library that apparently never considered that it would be installed anywhere other than next to the calling page. I can't reorganize the code without making major changes to the library. The biggest problem is that the library supports plugins, and when those have script-relative references (both to images and to other JS files), the references don't work if the lib is called  as described above. 

I may need to patch the lib to take an <install_dir>, & edit the plugins to prefix external references with it. I was hoping not to have to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short of rewriting the library and having it check for the appropriate directory the only solution I can think of is to include the views, library and supporting files in a directory structure that the library can access.  This of course would break MVC's convention over configuration way of finding views, so you would have to write a custom override of the way Razor looks for views, which is not too complex to do, but you might be making life more difficult for yourself down the road depending on your application. Your call which is the lesser of the two evils :) (I'd go for fixing the library)

Comment: yes, I think you're right. Looks like there's no way to do this using the default view resolution. Not even sure I could come up with a new way to resolve the view that would retain the request URL, and in any case, it would break the MVC conventions in a big way. In the short term, I'll probably host the library in a static page, and longer-term, patch the library to use an installation-directory setting.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a controller for handling you redirect logic - for example an "Images"controller. Register a global route in your Global.asax file, using the pattern (more on this type of pattern [here](http://www.adventuretechgroup.com/2011/02/making-a-useful-mvc3-global-action-filter/):

```
routes.MapRoute(

    "Images", // Route name

     "{xyz}/{controller}/{path}", // URL with parameters

     new {controller = "Images", action = "Index", path= UrlParameter.Optional} // Parameter defaults);
```

**In your controller:**

```
public ActionResult Index(string path)
{
    //format path, parse request segments, or do other work needed to Id file to return... 

    return base.File(path, "image/jpeg"); //once you have the path pointing to the right place...
}
```

Not sure if this solution will work for you, wish I could come up with something more elegant. Best of Luck!

Comment: Christopher, I don't think I can make this work -- aside from images and extensions, there are other files in the root of the jslibrary folder that I'd have to trap on an individual basis. I already have  IIS rewrite rules to change calls to the `images` and `extensions` directories in the library to the actual location, but the loose files are slipping through the cracks, and the cracks are the same for doing this with MVC routes. However, thanks for the link -- the global filter will come in handy for other stuff I'm working on. So, +1 for that!

Comment: I agree, seems like what you really need is to use RegEx to look for those patterns, and simply rewrite them. That has the benefit of being easy to remove once you fix that JS to play nice with your new backed architecture. I am no expert in URL rewriting, but [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972974.aspx) seems very helpful?

Answer (score 0):

Make a help function

```
@functions{

        public string AbsoluteUrl(string relativeContentPath)
        {
            Uri contextUri = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url;

            var baseUri = string.Format("{0}://{1}{2}", contextUri.Scheme,
               contextUri.Host, contextUri.Port == 80 ? string.Empty : ":" + contextUri.Port);

            return string.Format("{0}{1}", baseUri, VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute(relativeContentPath));
        }
    }
```

Calling

```
@AbsoluteUrl("~/Images/myImage.jpg") <!-- gives the full path like: http://localhost:54334/Images/myImage.jpg -->
```

This example are from
https://dejanvasic.wordpress.com/2013/03/26/generating-full-content-url-in-mvc/

Comment: thanks -- but I need to handle this at the routing level. Your example works when I can control the URL generation -- but in my case, the URLs are already expressed in a JavaScript library. I can't feed them into this function.